# Import multiple files from a plugged mobile device not working

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I have a simple input triggered when a button is clicked.

I can select multiple images when selecting files on my computer or external disk drive, but only one from a plugged mobile device.

How can I fix this ?

This is the input :

`<input type="file" id="fileSelector" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" style="display: none;" multiple/>`

Comment: The `style="display: none;"` doesn't help. But it is true, some mobile browsers do not support this, see: https://caniuse.com/input-file-multiple